# Use percentrank with dynamic range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of data that represents players and their stats each week. I then rank each individual stat category for the week using percentrank, certain stat has a multiplier value, and all of them are added up for a rating

What i need is a dynamic way to use percentrank because the number of players varies from week to week.

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NeCo.png)

Comment: well its ugly, works, and dynamic enough for the job since i know how many weeks, just not the amount of players. Probably used too many IF functions, but didnt want to miss something. 
 =ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A="","",arrayformula(if(A2:A="Week 1",PERCENTRANK(if(A2:A="Week 1",$C$2:$C,""), if(A2:A="Week 1",$C$2:$C,"")),if(A2:A="Week 2",PERCENTRANK(if(A2:A="Week 2",$C$2:$C,""), if(A2:A="Week 2",$C$2:$C,"")),"")))))