# Dynamically sum each row of an array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have tried multiple suggestions on here for other peoples situations. Mostly with mmult() and had no luck.

I have a dynamic range of values and need a dynamic way to sum each row of the array.

Here is a very basic way to explain my goal.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  | 3 |
| 2 |  | 2 | 4 |
| 1 |  | 1 | 2 |
|  | 2 | 3 | 5 |

[heres a sample workbook thats more detailed. The two sheets, one a simple version of my actual sheet, and a copy of the actual sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g9l1oGBk6pR83XYZYWn3V9sVisWiWZSlr92LuRX18J4/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in your `SIMPLE` tab:

```
=byrow(Q2:W,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,sum(Σ))))
```

Comment: Works for exactly what i asked for, thought i could just fill in the rest. Sadly i have an if condition I have to add to it, that i thout would fit right in. But theres a check box at the top of each column, and values only get included in the sum if true.

Comment: Try this in `Cell DA7` of your `actual sheet`: `=byrow(index(if(BF4:CZ4,BF7:CZ,)),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,sum(Σ))))`

Comment: Works perfect, had a head bump moment since i also divide it by 100 so that i can make it a percent but i found what spot to put it in....Could this work with percent rank aswell?   I had another question here, but i figured it out but its a really ugly formula.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75979922/use-percentrank-with-dynamic-range

Comment: Its kinda hard to troubleshoot based on a screenshot. Maybe post the question again with sample dataset sheet and expected output (manually entered) and hopefully someone on this forum will address it this time.

Comment: its inside of the sheet i shared, starting at BF in actual sheet. Every column is a rank multiplied by the value in in row 6 of each column. I did get it to work, other than idk how to add that multiplier in, think i might have reached its limit unless you can somehow combine two by lambda together.

Comment: Hey, thinks for all your help. It did end up being surronding the by column with a by row with the multiplier column. I never understood the bylambda function, and it would have came in handy a long time ago for me.